# how to make array 3 dimension with php?

Tags: php

help me please,, syntax eror

```
$Prodi = array("Ilmu Hukum" => array("Angkatan 2010" => array("Siswono","Hariono","Madun"),
                    "Teknik Informatika" => array("Angkatan 2010" => array("Atep","Ferdinan","I Made"),
                    "Akutansi" => array("Angkatan 2010" => array("Ridwan","Firman","Zulkifli")))));

while(list($key1) = each($Prodi)) {
    echo "$key1 : <br>";
    }
    while(list($key2,$val) = each($Prodi["$key1"])){

        echo "-$val<br>";
        }
            While(list($key3,$val) = each($Prodi["$key2"])){
            echo "-$val<br>";
        }
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Explain this some more please
Give info like what you expected to get, what you did get.

Comment: Just google it: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp

Comment: Same question as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373996/how-to-make-array-3-dimension-php-with-while Simply reposted since he got way downvoted, and wouldn't change the way he asks his question.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following code.

```
foreach($Prodi as $a1key => $a1val) {
    echo $a1key . '===' . json_encode($a1val) . '<br />';
    foreach($a1val as $a2key => $a2val) {
        echo $a2key . '===' . json_encode($a2val) . '<br />';    
        foreach($a2val as $a3key => $a3val) {
            echo $a3key . '===' . json_encode($a3val) . '<br />';        
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: NOTE that you can also use print_r instead of json_encode and do whatever you want to do with the array values.

Comment: I'm not sure but from the array code I think you declared it incorrectly as well. This might the array string that you are looking to have

`$Prodi = array("Ilmu Hukum" => array("Angkatan 2010" => array("Siswono","Hariono","Madun")),
               "Teknik Informatika" => array("Angkatan 2010" => array("Atep","Ferdinan","I Made")),
               "Akutansi" => array("Angkatan 2010" => array("Ridwan","Firman","Zulkifli")));`

Comment: okee thanks for answer,, i will to try with foreach,,, 
thanks mr.dhamra

Comment: Hi Dede - if that solves your problem, please accept the answer.